# Life of the prophet Muhammad, peace and bless be upon him

Tags: prophet-muhammad, books, seerah

السلام عليكم

I seek for the biography of the prophet Muhammad, peace and bless be upon him.

Can you suggest the best book in English?

شكرا لكم

Comment: waalekumussalam Ar Raheeq Al Makhtoom "The Sealed Nectar"  https://archive.org/details/TheSealedNectar_201312

Answer (score 1):

There are several of these books. I would advice for a translation of one of the early biographers such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0196360331) (Ibn Ishaq is a fairely respected biographer of the prophet), but the English may seem too heavy. therefore, instead, I would point you to [this book](http://www.amazon.fr/Life-Prophet-Muhammad-Leila-Azzam/dp/0946621020), also available in PDF (google search it).

[This website](http://www.techofheart.co/2012/08/best-biography-prophet-muhammad-english.html) actually gives several PDFs (copyright free) and has a comprehensive comparison. This comparison is relevant because the *best* book for you may not be the best book for someone else: it depends on what you are looking for. For example, you may prefer a book that is more "in phase" with the contemporary world, or a book that is based on the [earliest traditions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594771537).

Finally, what I would really advice are *video* lectures. Amr Khaled gave a series, some time ago, called "'Ala Khuta al Habib" (on the footsteps of the beloved). If you can find it in [DVD](http://www.islamicbookstore.com/a5167.html) subtitled in English (check carefully if there are subtitles), I would immensely recommend it. He also wrote a book on it, but I don't know if there are translations. But yes, now that I thought about it, it would be my go to choice.

Comment: Honestly the biograhpy of ibn Ishaq or Ibn Hischaam are very ambivalent as some of his narration have been declared as odd tales. But most scholars agree on his narration of the maghazi! But the website you linked provides a lot of useful links and sources, jazaka Allah khair!